# ADC:How to convert pressure K Pa to Bar?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc

I am interfacing Pressure sensor MPL115A1 to PIC controller.Sensor have 10 bit ADC.

Sensor give me minimum 0 step to maximum 1023 step.

"0" step denotes 50KPa and "1023" denotes 110KPa.

My question is I have to convert this **KPa to Bar** form.

Exam: if i get ADC step "0" then I want to convert 50KPa to Bar.

How can i do this??

Comment: Do it with MATHS!

Answer (score 2):

1. Calculate kPa pressure value from ADC value.
2. Apply the unit conversion factor 1 bar = 100 kPa.

Comment: Can you explain in detail??? if you write some demo C code then it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @shailkorat: I don't like to give complete solutions "for free". Try writing something yourself, and then if you run into problems, post your attempt and we can help you improve it.

Comment: If you are unclear on how to perform the calculation itself, the first step is to consider how you would do it using only a pen, paper, and basic calculator.

Comment: @shailkorat All calculations, except for kPa => bar, are discussed in the datasheet. Converting to bar shouldn't be too difficult with the above answer.